# TypeMap in Java

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I want to implement such a map,

`Map<Class<T>, T> m;`

in which, I can get a generic object of type T, given the class of T.

I know you may say, you can wrap a `Map<String, Object>` and use casting to archive this.

I know this.

But imagine the map is `Map<Class<T>, Collection<T>>`, in which, the value is a very large collection.

I don't want to traverse the collection and cast every object, since the collection is too large.

So? what do I do?

Comment: Do you mean "wrap a Map<Class, Object>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to traverse the collection and cast every object, since the collection is too large.

I wouldn't worry about it because

- you should never need to do this
- generics are a compile time check so casting to a generic doesn't do anything at runtime.

e.g. If `T extends Object`, casting a `Object` to `T` doesn't do anything. Similarly cast `Collection` to `Collection<T>` doesn't do anything at runtime.

> But imagine the map is Map<Class<T>, Collection<T>>, in which, the value is a very large collection.

If you imagine this will do something, casting is not the answer. You may need to convert the contents of the Collection but that is completely different in Java.

Answer (score 4):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has something similar, it's called [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html).

You can read more about it [in a dedicated Wiki section](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap).

But apparently what you need is a `ClassToInstanceMultimap`. There is none yet, but you could file a feature request.

Comment: Thank you for this! I did not know that. But I think i'll give the best answer to @Peter Lawrey. His answer really solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as Java uses type erasure, an implementation will in fact have the type of a

```
Map<?, ?> = Map<Object, Object>
```

You can trivially write a safe accessor method that gives you the desired type safety, and e.g. does a `instanceOf` check:

```
public class InstanceMap extends HashMap<Class<?>, Object> {
    public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> cls) {
        Object o = super.get(cls);
        if (o != null && cls.isInstance(o)) {
            return (T) o;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public <T> void putInstance(Class<T> cls, T value) {
        super.put(cls, value);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public Object get(Object key) {
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

This will work fine unless you start using types that themselves are generic. `Class<? super T>` will then help a bit. But overall, it mostly gives you a *false sense of type safety*. This kind of map does not give you the strong type safety you are used to. In the end, it is little more than a cast.

I have used such maps before, but after using them for 1-2 years I in the end largely eliminated them again from my code during cleanup phase. They were a hack, and did not give me as much benefits as I expected them to give.