# Java Stream.map() on Subclasses with Wildcards Not Working

Tags: java

I have two classes `ChildA` and `ChildB` which are subclasses of `Parent`.

I am given a list of `Parent` and want to use Stream to map them to a `Map<? extends Parent, List<? extends Parent>>`

The issue is it seems the `.map` part is removing the subclass. Here is some sample code illustrating my problem:

```java
items.stream()
        .map(item -> item.isA() ? item.getA() : item.getB()) //<--- issue here, returns List<Parent> instead of List<? extends Parent>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getClass()));
```

With the above, the output is: `Map<? extends Class, List<Parent>>` but I want `Map<?extends Class, List<? extends Parent>>` so I could then do something like:

`map.get(A.class)` -> `List<A>`

So I can easily assign two variables:

```
List<A> a = map.get(a.class);
List<b> b = map.get(b.class);
```

Where as right now I would have to do something like:
`map.get(A.class).stream().map(A::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Is there a way to get my desired result?

EDIT:

Here is a minimum reproducible example: https://replit.com/@rgurn/MinExample?v=1#Main.java

Note it was not my design choice to make the container class `Item` and I cannot change it.

Comment: How is `items` declared?

Comment: `items` is essentially a `List<Container>` where `Container` can hold either `A` or `B`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: Apart from the code actually producing `Map<Class<?>, List<? extends Parent>>` doesn't specifying the type on the left hand of the assignment fixes the problem?

Comment: Here is an example https://replit.com/@rgurn/MinExample?v=1#Main.java @Robert. user16320675, this should be made clear by the example code I published.

Comment: The problem @user16320675 is that I would like that list to preserve the subclasses childA and childB, rather than be a `List<Parent>`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @user16320675 ahh I see, this is where my holes in understanding Java are showing. So you cannot have a List<? extends Parent> at all? In that case I suppose I cannot have that nice 'one-liner' to create that map to each subclass of `Parent`

Comment: @ragurney, you can't preserve `ChildA` and `ChildB` directly in a list. If you write a `Pair<F, S>` class, you can create a `Pair<List<ChildA>, List<ChildB>>` though.

Comment: Thanks all, it seems I cannot do what I wanted due to my misunderstanding of `List`. @user16320675 if you would like to write up your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: It would help if you would show expected output for input.

Comment: The ACTUAL output is: `Map<? extends Class, List<Parent>>` but I want `Map<?extends Class, List<? extends Parent>>` so I could then do something like: `map.get(A.class)` -> `List<A>`

Comment: if using `Map<?extends Class, List<? extends Parent>>`, get() will not return a `List<A>)`

Comment: Yes, and this is the question I was asking: is there any way to actually get a collection like what I want from `Items`. It sounds like no. I'll probably resort to `Pair` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is what I came up with. Do it the way you were but you will need to rebuild the lists by casting.

```
List<Item> items = List.of(new Item("a", new A()),
                new Item("b", new B()));
    
Map<Class<?>, List<Parent>> map = items
                .stream()
                .map(item -> item.isA() ? item.getA() : item.getB())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getClass()));
        
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Parent p :map.get(A.class)) {
     list.add(A.class.cast(p));
}
```

This doesn't scale well but you can always cast the contents of the List using the map Key.  You should not get any class cast exceptions since you are separating them in the map according to class.

Comment: The goal I have is to disentangle the two types from `items` so I could assign two variables:  I can easily assign two variables:

`List<A> a = map.get(a.class);`
`List<b> b = map.get(b.class);`

It seems like this solution would still just return a list of `Parent` for each key.

Comment: So, for  given sub  classes A and B of Parent you want to have List<A> and  List<B> as the Map values?  If so, that clears up a lot but I may delete my answer since my solution doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes that's correct, and very sorry that wasn't too clear from the onset. I am trying to find a somewhat short and graceful way to split out these two subclasses from this list of container instances into two respective lists.

Comment: This approach is sadly not scaleable and doesn't really produce the desired map, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

After the sad realization I had a misunderstanding of `List` and couldn't do what I initially tried, I ended up going with a `Pair` based approach like @M. Prokhorov suggested:

```java
    Pair<ArrayList<A>, ArrayList<B>> collection = items.stream()
        .map(i -> i.isA() ? i.getA() : i.getB())
        .collect(() -> Pair.of(new ArrayList<A>(), new ArrayList<B>()), (p, u) -> {
          if (u instanceof A) {
            p.getFirst().add((A) u);
          } else {
            p.getSecond().add((B) u);
          }
        }, (p1, p2) -> {
          p1.getFirst().addAll(p2.getFirst());
          p1.getSecond().addAll(p2.getSecond());
        });

List<A> aList = collection.getFirst();
List<B> bList = collection.getSecond();
```

Overall I'm not too happy about it. Something just feels off, maybe I should just KISS. If anyone has a better method of doing this I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: Using my approach, you can have any number of subclasses. It is pretty clean, because, eventhough you need to cast, only uses the HashMap as a private attribute and thus has full control over it.

Comment: @Cactusroot As I understand it, the Item class cannot be changed.

Comment: @WJS It definitly can, simply because any library would implement a clean variant. And even if it cannot be, you can just replace Item::get with item -> item.isA() ? item.getA() : item.getB().

Comment: @Cactusroot I;m not talking technically.  The OP said *Note it was not my design choice to make the container class Item and I cannot change it.*  I may be taking that statement too literally though.

Comment: @WJS You're right, but I wouldn't accept such an approach. The whole type thing is not only dirty, overdesigned and inefficient, but you do not meat your cast assertions, because you can simply pass any String to that constructor.

Comment: @Cactusroot I work in a very large company and the `Item` class is an internal (and auto-generated) library used throughout thousands of modules. While I completely agree with you and your points, I simply don't have ownership over that code base and cannot change the class.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still don't think you need it, this a clean implementation of Item.class:

```
public class Item {
    private final Parent item;

    public Item(Parent item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Parent get() {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isA() {
        return item instanceof A;
    }

    public boolean isB() {
        return item instanceof B;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return (A) item;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return (B) item;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Your `.map`-call does nothing except for mapping an `Item` to a `Parent` (whether or not item is A, it just adds the attribute `item` back in).

But you cannot collect your `Stream` as the desired `Map` anyway ([there is no such `Map` in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375802)), so I made one for you:

```
public class ClassMap<V> {
    private final HashMap<Class<? extends V>, List<? extends V>> map;

    public ClassMap() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public ClassMap(@NonNull List<V> input) {
        this();
        for (V v : input) add(v);
    }

    public <W extends V> void add(@NonNull W item) {
        Class<W> clazz = (Class<W>) item.getClass();
        List<W> list = (List<W>) map.get(clazz);
        if (list == null) map.put(clazz, list = new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(item);
    }

    public <W extends V> List<W> get(@NonNull Class<W> clazz) {
        return (List<W>) map.get(clazz);
    }

    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }
}
```

You can create one like this: `ClassMap<Parent> map = new ClassMap<>(items.stream().map(Item::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 12, you can use a [teeing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) and collect into a pair by using standard collector chains rather than your own function-based custom collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.filtering;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

Pair<List<A>, List<B>> lists = items.stream().collect(
    Collectors.teeing(
        filtering(Parent::isA, mapping(Parent::getA, toList())),
        filtering(Parent::isB, mapping(Parent::getB, toList())),
        Pair::of
    )
);

List<A> as = lists.getFirst();
List<B> bs = lists.getSecond();
```

This, of course, assumes that `Parent::isA`, `Parent::isB` and other methods exist, but this can be rolled added easily in form of static utility functions.